# Zubehör - Der oder Das?

Tags: gender

I stumbled upon both these sentences:

> Wir müssen den Zubehör selbst bezahlen.
>
> Wir müssen das Zubehör selbst bezahlen.

Which got me confused. I thought one of them had to be wrong, so I went to check what was the right answer [here](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/zubeh%C3%B6r:N:M:N), and to my surprise... it seems like it has two genders??

Is this right? Does this noun have two possible genders??

Is that independent of the context?

Comment: Never ever used or heart "der Zubehör".  Probably in other regions than in North Gemany.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and yes - Nouns sometimes have 2 different genders in German, normally these are regional differences or a not-yet finally settled gender with a loanword (not the case here).

I personally would, however, never use *der Zubehör*. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zubehoer) is a bit more specific than canoo and at least mentions that *der Zubehör* is rarely used.

Comment: *Der Zubehör* is old-fashioned, probably from law speech. See *der Behör* as a reference.

Comment: Never heard or said "Der Zubehör" in my life. But then again, I am just a humble native speaker :-)